# Only the first LINQ .Count() statement works

Tags: c#, csv, linq

I've tried to get data from cvs file and everything went smoothly but I can't use LINQ on it,first statement always works but then the rest always returns 0

CVS header:car_make,car_model,car_model_year,car_vin

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("D:\\C#\\CSV_Deserialization\\obj\\Debug\\net7.0\\Cars1.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        //csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<MyCarMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Cars>();
           
        int HondaCounter = records.Count(car => car.CarMake == "Honda");
        int ChevroletCounter = records.Count(car => car.CarMake == "Chevrolet");
        int PontiacCounter = records.Count(car => car.CarMake == "Pontiac");

        Console.WriteLine(HondaCounter);
        Console.WriteLine(ChevroletCounter);
        Console.WriteLine(PontiacCounter);
          
    }
}
```

```
namespace CSV_Deserialization
{
    public class Cars
    {
        [Name("car_make")]
        public string CarMake { get; set;}
        [Name("car_model")]
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        [Name("car_model_year")]
        public int CarModelYear { get; set; }
        [Name("car_vin")]
        public string CarVin {  get; set; }

    }
}
```

```
namespace CSV_Deserialization
{
    public class MyCarMap :ClassMap<Cars>
    {
        public MyCarMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.CarMake).Name("car_make");
            Map(m => m.CarModel).Name("car_model");
            Map(m => m.CarModelYear).Name("car_model_year");
            Map(m => m.CarVin).Name("car_vin");
        }
       
    }
}
```

It doesn't work with Map or Indexes

I've tried changing csv,indexes and checked them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` after `.GetRecords<Cars>()`:

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<Cars>().ToArray();
```

The `GetRecords<T>` method will return an `IEnumerable<T>`. It's reading the records until the end on the first `Count()` call and keeps pointing to the end on the second and third calls. That's why it returns the correct count only on the first.

By calling `ToArray` or `ToList`, we are *materializing* the records.